# yum remove doesn't remove things completely?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, yum, remove

I am trying to remove apache completely from my server,which is a ec2 instance, running Amazonian linux v2.6xx.

Lets assume I have a file in /etc/httpd/conf/xyz.txt

I am using the following code :

```
yum remove httpd
```

when I try to `cd /etc/httpd` I get "there is no such directory" error.

Next, if I install httpd again, using this : `yum install httpd`, and then if I look in `/etc/httpd/conf/` I still have that file as it is.. untouched..

How is this possible ?

How do I "Clean" this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yum/rpm will not remove things it did not put into place (unless someone does it in the scripts, but only ISVs with a few screws loose do that). I highly suspect that you typoed your `cd` command, and that the directory did actually exist.

Comment: I "CD"ed into proper directory, I repeated it many times (install/remove) and confirmed that it was happening.. 
So no chance of typos.. And I confirm that the directory wasn't there.. (I tried winscp to browse through to it..)